# Run linux terminal commands from python GUI tkinter

Tags: linux, tkinter, subprocess

I want to run linux terminal commands from tkinter. So whatever linux command i will type in tkinter "Entry" widget and press button  to be run in terminal.

If you see the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
root = Tk()
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0) 

def print_entry1():
   subprocess.run(entry1.get())
Button(root, text="entry1", command=print_entry1).grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

You will find that it works for a "single-word" commands like pwd, whoami, ls.
But if you add space and some flag / parameter during typing it gives errors... for example it can not understand ls -l command.
As soon as space is introduced during typing it gives errors...

Could you pls advise...
Thks so much.

Comment: `subrocess.run` expects a *list* of arguments. If you're passing in a string (which it looks like you are), you will need to either (a) split the command yourself, possibly using `shlex.split`, or (b) set `shell=True` when calling `subprocess.run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `import shlex` and then replace

```py
subprocess.run(entry1.get())
```

with

```py
subprocess.run(shlex.split(entry1.get()))
```

That will convert the string the user entered into a list.